# Sets and combinatorics simplification

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$|\{A\in P(\{1,2,……,2n-1\})||A|\leq n\}|?$$

---

My attempt:

---

The question is similar to pick $k$ balls from $2n-1$ Balls while $0\leq k \leq n$.which means:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n-1}{k}  = \binom{2n-1}{n}+\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}+ \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}}{2} = $$
$$\binom{2n-1}{n}+\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}}{2} = \binom{2n-1}{n}+ \frac{2^{2n-1}}{2} = \binom{2n-1}{n}+ 2^{2n-2} $$
While I used the binom and the fact that for all $0\leq k \leq n-1$ : $\binom{2n-1}{k} = \binom{2n-1}{2n-k-1} $ and thus $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}= \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k} $.

I'm trying to think of simpler solution without sum operation and didn’t succed.

Comment: You  have the right idea & there isn't anything simpler but you have mis-calculated. Note that the term $\binom {2n-1}{n}$ on the RHS in your 1st displayed line also occurs incorrectly as the term with $k=n$ in the second summation.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Every step OP has written is mathematically correct. Just because $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ appears twice, that does not imply a mistake. If you think an equation OP has written is invalid, you need to provide a value of $n$ for which the equation is untrue. If no such $n$ exists, then your complaint is invalid, and you should delete your comment.